# Example of conditional expectation from the Radon-Nikodym theorem

Tags: probability, probability-theory, measure-theory, conditional-expectation, radon-nikodym

I'm studying probability following Shiryaev's book, and I'm trying to understand how the Radon-Nikodym theorem applies in an actual case where I can calculate the conditional expectation of a random variable $X$ given a sub $\sigma$-field $\mathcal{G}$ in the $(\Omega,\mathcal{F}, \mathbb{P})$ from this theorem.

The book says that the conditional expectation $E(X|\mathcal{G})$ is the Radon-Nikodym derivative:

$$ E(X|\mathcal{G}) =  \dfrac{d\mathbb{Q}}{d\mathbb{P}}(\omega),  $$ where:

$$ Q(A) = \int_A Xd\mathbb{P} \ \ , \ A \in \mathcal{G} $$

I understand that the theorem is important to ensure the existance of the conditional expectation, but I am having trouble in actually using the theorem to actually FIND the random variable $E(X|\mathcal{G})$.

So I considered a toy example then to see how the theorem applies, and did it also by the definition. Consider a probability space $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, \mathbb{P})$ with $\Omega= (0,1]$, $\mathcal{F}$ the Borel set in $(0,1]$ and $\mathbb{P}$ the Lebesgue measure and consider the random variable $X(\omega)=\omega$. Consider in the same probability space $Y(\omega)= \omega \mathbb{I}_{(0,0.5]}(\omega)$ and take finally $\mathcal{G}_Y$ the $\sigma$-field generated by the rv $Y$.

Let's evaluate $E(X|\mathcal{G}_Y)$. I know by definition that it must satisfy $E(X|\mathcal{G}_Y)(\omega) = \dfrac{d\mathbb{Q}}{d\mathbb{P}}(\omega)$, but I'll go the other way around first.

As suggested in the comments, we can take a look at the elements of $Y^{-1}((-\infty,a])$ that generate the $\sigma$-algebra $\mathcal{G}_Y$. The random variable takes non-null values only in the set $(0,1/2]$ by construction, so:

$$ Y^{-1}(-\infty, a])  =\begin{cases}
\emptyset  & a<0 \\
(1/2, 1] & a =0, \\
\left(0,a\right] \cup (1/2, 1]  & 0 < a \leq1/2  \\
\Omega & a >1/2
\end{cases} $$

This seems right to me because it sums up to one if I use the Lebesgue measure in this set and the resulting $F_Y$ would be an increasing function. So $\mathcal{G}_Y$ is the $\sigma$-algebra generated by these sets.

Let's go back to the problem. Because I conveniently defined my sub-sigmafield, I know that it's equivalent to evaluating $E(X|Y=y)$ so I'll study the probability density of $ X|Y=y$. Take for notation $Z=X|Y=y$ and consider the set of preimages:

$$ Z^{-1}\left((-\infty,a]\right) =\begin{cases}
\emptyset  & a<0 \\
(y, 1] & a =0 \\
(y, 1]\cup \left(0,a \right] & 0 < a \leq y \\
\Omega & a >y
\end{cases} $$

Taking the Lebesgue measure on these sets, I'll have:

$$ F_{X|Y=y}(a) = (1-y)\mathbb{I}_{\{0\}}(a) + \left( (1-y) + a \right)\mathbb{I}_{(0,y]}(a), $$ which I can use as a fact to write the Lebesgue integral as a Lebesgue-Stieltjes integral.

Hence the conditional expectation is:

$$ E(X|\mathcal{G}_Y) := E(X|Y=y) = \int Z d\mathbb{P} = \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} x dF_{X|Y=y} = y, $$ for values of $y \in (0,1/2]$, which is according to the intuition of the formulation of $Y(\omega)$.

Now let's try to assess it using the Radon-Nikodym theorem. By the definition:

$$ Q(A) = \int_A X d\mathbb{P}, A \in \mathcal{G}_Y $$

I need to verify that $Q(A) = \int_A X d\mathbb{P}$ for $A \in \mathcal{G}_Y$. So I'm talking about verifying that this holds for any set in the $\sigma$-field generated by the set of preimages of $Y(\omega$), that is: $$\sigma\left(\{\emptyset, \Omega, \{(0, a], \forall a \in (0,1/2]\}, (1/2, 1] \}\right),$$ where I denote here the $\sigma(\cdot)$ as the $\sigma$-algebra generated by the elements.

For the non-trivial case, it suffices considering only sets of the form $A=[0,y]$, with $y\in[0,1/2]$ to work with, as well as the set $(1/2,1]$, so I'll have:

$$ \mathbb{Q}(A) = \int_{A} Xd\mathbb{P} := \int_{A} x dF_x = \int_{0}^{y} x dx = \dfrac{y^2}{2} $$

Then again for the set $A=(1/2,1]$

$$ \mathbb{Q}(A) = \int_{A} Xd\mathbb{P} := \int_{A} x dF_x = \int_{1/2}^{1} x dx = 0.375 $$ which then leads to:

$$ \dfrac{d\mathbb{Q}}{d\mathbb{P}}(A) =\begin{cases}
\omega & \omega \in (0,1/2] \\
0 & \omega \in (1/2,1] \\
\end{cases}, $$ which is in fact what we intended to show.

Is my idea correct? I think my problem is more conceptual, like: when I take the derivative with respect to the Lebesgue measure, will it always be the "standard" derivative $\dfrac{d}{dx}$?

Comment: Your formula for $E(X|\mathcal G_Y)$ doesn't seem right. On the one hand, $E(X)=1/2$. But also you should have $E(E(X|\mathcal G_Y))=E(X)$. If $E(X|\mathcal G_Y)$ were equal to $Y/2$, which is $\le 1/4$ (because $Y\le 1/2$), you would have $E(X)\le 1/4$.

As a start, can you describe $\mathcal G_Y$? (Suggestion: change $\Omega$ to $(0,1]$. The point $0$ that's been removed has probability $0$ anyway, and its removal eliminates the cumbersome fact that $\{Y=0\}=\{X=0\}\cup\{X>1/2\}$.)

Comment: Hey @JohnDawkins, thank you for noticing that! I'll make sure to correct it, got it all messed up because of the indicator function. I tried to make a toy example that turned out to be more complicated than I thought, but now it's interesting!! haha

Comment: The point is that you want a function $f$ such that $\int_A f(x) \, dx=\mathbb{Q}(A)$ for all Borel $A \subset [0,1]$. Specializing to intervals of the form $[0,a]$, you see that it is necessary that $f(x)=x 1_{[0,1/2]}(x)$ almost everywhere by just taking the ordinary derivative, and then you check that this is also sufficient.

Comment: That being said the Radon-Nikodym theorem is not really meant to be especially constructive. It just guarantees the density exists. It gives a mnemonic for how to find the density when the base measure is Lebesgue measure, but that's more or less it. Normally the base measure in probability theory is *fundamentally abstract*, and so you never explicitly write the conditional expectation as a function of $\omega$ in its own right. You just express it in terms of whatever random variable(s) or event(s) generated the sub $\sigma$-field (in the context of the question that means $Y$).

Comment: @Ian yes, I found it not very constructive indeed. The usage and importance of the theorem to me was so far in proving that the conditional expectation does exist, provided that if follows the requirements of the Radon-Nikodym theorem. But I believed I could somehow use it in some simpler/toy cases to get to the actual $E(X|\mathcal{G})$ by differentiating $Q(A) = \int_A X d\mathbb{P}$. That's why I wrote it.

Comment: @JohnDawkins I think I got it in fact now, thanks for the suggestion.  I let in my edited post a clarification question on why I can take the "standard" derivative in that case. I think you should answer it formally, so I can give you the right answer - bcs you answered my question.

Comment: You've found that $d\Bbb Q/d\Bbb P(\omega) = \omega$ for $\omega\in(0,.5]$ What about for $\omega\in(.5,1]$?

Comment: @JohnDawkins thank you! I wrote it  down, I believe now it's complete.

Comment: How did you arrive at $0$ rather than $3/4$, for the value of the RN derivative on $(1/2,1]$?

Comment: @JohnDawkins I did as $\mathbb{Q}(A) = \int_{A} Xd\mathbb{P} := \int_{A} x dF_x = \int_{1/2}^{1} x dx = 0.375$ so if I take the derivative, it's a constant and will be $0$. I edited the text in details of my derivation of $d\mathbb{Q}/d\mathbb{P}$.

Comment: @JohnDawkins if it resulted in $3/4$ it would be incorrect, wouldn't it? Because my conditional expectation is $E(X|Y=y) = y $ for $y \in (0,1/2]$.

Comment: @YetAnotherUsr: Concerning $3/4$: 
$$
\Bbb Q(1/2]=\int_{(1/2,1]}Xd\Bbb  P= \Bbb  E[X; 1/2<X\le 1] = 3/8={3\over 4}\Bbb P(1/2,1].
$$
Notice that $\Bbb E[X|Y](\omega)$ is constant for $\omega(1/2,1]$. By the above computation that constant must be $3/4$.

Comment: @JohnDawkins I got it, but then where is my $E(X|\mathcal{G}_Y)$ written in the first step wrong? I calculated it from the pdf $F_{X|Y=y}(a) = (1-y)\mathbb{I}_{\{0\}}(a) + \left( (1-y) + a \right)\mathbb{I}_{(0,y]}(a)$ which I wrote in my question.

Comment: @JohnDawkins your answer makes sense, because if $Y(\omega)=0$ it means that it fell in the region $(1/2,1]$ and the expected value for that should be $3/4$, but I can't see how my $\int X dF_{X|Y=y}$ is wrong... I'll try to do it again :)